# Problem updating to a specific version of Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an old version of flutter.
I would like to update the version but not to the latest. I tried the command

```
flutter upgrade
```

and then

```
flutter downgrade 3.3.1
```

but it only returns me to the version I had previously and not to an intermediate version between my old one and the latest version available.

What can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To downgrade to a specific version of Flutter, you can use the following command:

> flutter upgrade --force-downgrade -v enter your version here

Replace  with the version number you want to downgrade to (e.g., 3.1.1). The --force-downgrade option is necessary as it allows you to downgrade to a previous version of Flutter.

Comment: I try
```
flutter upgrade --force-downgrade -v3.0.0
```
but return
```
 Could not find an option named "force-downgrade".
```

Comment: The --force-downgrade option may not be available in the latest version of Flutter. As an alternative, you can try the following steps to downgrade to a specific version of Flutter:

Remove the current version of Flutter:

flutter doctor --clear-cache
Download the desired version of Flutter from the official website: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases

Extract the archive to your preferred location and add it to your PATH.